# Go lang nested slice size allocation

Tags: go, slice

For the code below, I want to know how can I allocate the size to `val` slice of `mystruct` structure?

```
            package main

            import (
                "fmt"
            )

            type mystruct struct {
                val []int
                key int
            }

            type mystruct2 struct {
                mm []mystruct
            }

            func main() {
                s1 := make([]mystruct, 2)
                fmt.Println(s1)
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to allocate the `val` slice with n amount upon initializing a `mystruct` structure you can do so like this:

```
m := mystruct{
  val: make([]int, 2), // or make([]int, 0, 2)
}
```

You can also provide a factory function such as:

```
func newMystruct(n int) mystruct {
  return mystruct{
    val: make([]int, n), // or make([]int, 0, n)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to allocate the slice in the nested `struct`:

```
s1 := make([]mystruct, 2)
for i := range s1 {
    s1[i].val = make([]int, 2)  // replace 2 with whatever size you want
}
```